# bootstrap 3 - Disable navbar-toggle stacking on mobile phones

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How to disable navbar in Twitter Bootstrap 3 to stack toggle button into new line, when the page is accessed via mobile phone?

I always get something like this:

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [toile-libre.org](http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1463699669.png))</sub>

I've tried everything, from adding custom CSS to modifying `.less` files and further recompiling the whole Bootstrap style (I've been changing `@grid-float-breakpoint` variable and I even have played with `navbar.less`), but unfortunately I had no success.

Can somebody help me, please? I'm desperate because I've lost a whole day trying to fix this.

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Have you tried leveraging a media query on your css class that styles the navigation? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, I had to add `width` attribute to the div container which has these two buttons from the right. The div was improperly resizing, hence it was putting the second (toggle) button in the new line.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the collapse class from the menu, and deleting the button:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.navbar-toggle` has property `float: right;`. Check the HTML-code of your `navbar`. The toggle button should be placed first, before the other parts of the menu.